# Cannot install DDEV from PowerShell

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am trying to install DDEV from PowerShell, following these instructions: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/windows-development-environment/installing-drupal-with-ddev-in-wsl2-on-windows/installing-docker-ddev-drupal-in-wsl2

I am able to run the first PowerShell command (in a "Run As Administrator" window) just fine:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072;
```

This works with no errors. The following command:

```
iex ((New-Object 
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ddev/ddev/master/scripts/install_ddev_wsl2_docker_inside.ps1'))
```

returns the following error:

```
Docker Desktop integration is enabled with the default distro and it must but turned off.
At line:36 char:5
+     throw "Docker Desktop integration is enabled with the default dis ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Docker Desktop ...but turned off.:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Docker Desktop integration is enabled with the default distro and it must but turned off
```

I did have Docker Desktop installed at one point, but I uninstalled it. It no longer appears in Control Panel --> Programs and Features. If I run the command `wsl.exe -l -v` in a regular (non-Admin) PowerShell window it returns the following:

```
NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
```

If I run the same command in the admin PowerShell window I get "Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions..."

Where is the admin PowerShell seeing the remnants of Docker Desktop and how do I get rid of it entirely?

Comment: Have you considered removing Ubuntu then reinstalling it?  What version of WSL do you have installed? The current supported version of WSL is installed through the Windows Store, you should make sure, that is the version you have installed. It appears the PowerShell script associated with DDEV has some issues being ran as a non-Administrator since at least 2023. The addition of `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` would make the script require elevated permissions out of the gate. You would have to set the system's execution policy to Bypass to avoid that which is NOT a secure configuration.

Comment: Running the command in question: `wsl bash -c "test -d /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop >/dev/null 2>&1"` gives "Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore". It thinks it's finding docker desktop because it's returning a non-blank error. And it's not finding any distros because I'm running this as Administrator user, not my regular user.

Comment: No, no, no. Nothing is working right! Why is this block of code: `# Make sure default distro an ubuntu release if (-not( wsl -e grep ^NAME=.Ubuntu //etc/os-release)) { throw "Your installed WSL2 distro does not seem to be Ubuntu. You can certainly use DDEV with WSL2 in another distro, but this script is oriented to Ubuntu." }` not throwing an error if my Admin Powershell version of wsl doesn't detect Ubuntu (or any other distro for that matter)?

Comment: Your default distribution IS Ubuntu so that evaluation would not return True. (Not true is false)…

Answer (score -1):

Run the script as a regular user, NOT from an Administrator account. The instructions are incorrect, in this instance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).